# check user session in javascript

Tags: javascript, session

I need Your advice. I needed to check if user logged. I got from back-end session, than created hidden div and put data from session in this div. In javascript code I got data from this div and check if user session exist all ok else redirect user to log in page. Is it good practice? Or this is bad way. Thank you!

Comment: Session doesn't mean the user has access, an authentication_id together with the session should be used to validate the user. And this should be saved in a cookie.

Comment: if you work on the same domain you can use document.cookie. but if you work cross domain the cookie is not accessable in most modern browsers. best practice is to check serverside if the cookie exists, is correct and not timed out. so the client just gets a error message and has not to handle the session.